# Could not import package

Tags: go

I have this problem that the miner import is not resolved, which is my own code and its corresponding module in Go.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/JonathanDiz/blockchain-miner/pkg/minero" Import the mining package using the Go module import convention
)
```

> could not import github.com/JonathanDiz/blockchain-miner/pkg/minero (no required module provides package "github.com/JonathanDiz/blockchain-miner/pkg/minero")compilerBrokenImport

I uploaded my project to GitHub and the same error continues. How do I fix it?

I'm having trouble importing module into Go

Comment: @DarkBee I have already written my request in English, to open my consultation ticket

Comment: Please format the question properly, I don't think "*Import the mining pa....*" is an actual line in your import?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I'm having trouble importing the miner module from my GitHub repository.

Comment: Your `go.mod` states your module is named `blockchain-miner`, you then ostensibly are trying to import it into some other package, but the import path of that `pkg/minero` package would be `blockchain-miner/pkg/minero` because it's, basically, "what is written in go.mod plus the pathname relative to where that go.mod is". All-in-all, please start with the "Tutorial: Getting Started" and "Tutorial: Create a Module" (and possibly others as well) [there](https://go.dev/doc/); note that it contains a whole _section_ dedicated to writing modules. See also [this](https://golang.org/ref/mod).

Comment: IOW, if you want your `pkg/minero` to be importable using `github.com/JonathanDiz/blockchain-miner/pkg/minero`, your go.mod should state the module is `github.com/JonathanDiz/blockchain-miner`.